# How to select data of a built-in AnyLogic-database within an AnyLogic-class?

Tags: sql, database, class, anylogic

in my anylogic-model i want to query some data from the build-in-database. Within a function in an agent-type that's no problem. For better encapsulating i want to put my code into a class.

I already searched the AnyLogic-help, but i couldn't find the correct way to access the database from within a class.

The provided examples only work within the agent-type (https://help.anylogic.com/nav/0_15_10), since the function is provided by the abstract class Utilities which every agent is inherited from (https://help.anylogic.com/topic/com.anylogic.help/html/javadoc/com/anylogic/engine/Utilities.html).

```
Tuple item = selectFrom( team_knowledge ).
                        where( team_knowledge.idteam_social.eq( idmember ) ).
                        where( team_knowledge.idteam_technology.eq( idtechnology ) ).
                        firstResult(team_knowledge.id, team_knowledge.idteam_social,
                            team_knowledge.idteam_technology, team_knowledge.is_skill,
                            team_knowledge.necessary_skill);

Error: The method selectFrom(Qteam_knowledge) is undefined for the type TeamKnowledgeModel
```

Do you can name the correct class to use for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just have the class accept an instance of any `Agent` in the model within its constructor. Then it has to use that to do any queries (e.g., `agent.selectFrom`).

That is, the class stores an instance of an `Agent` which it delegates queries to.